# MyContract.methods.addData doesn't work from nodejs web3

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am connecting to my Solidity contract through Node.js and web3. I am able to read information, but when trying to add an element to an array it is not added.

The Solidity method:

```
bytes32[20] bytesArray;

function add(uint8 id, bytes32 s) public {
  bytesArray[id] = s;
}
```

The call from my Node.js file:

```
var myContractABI = <the_abi>;
var contractAddress = '0x...';
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractABI, contractAddress);
myContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
```

Add a value:

```
myContract.methods.add(0, web3.utils.asciiToHex("some string")).call()
  .then(receipt => {
      console.log(" added? " + receipt); // returns [object Object]
});
```

Then to get the value:

```
myContract.methods.getArray().call()
  .then(receipt => {
      console.log("full array " + receipt);
});
```

The array comes back but all its values are still empty, `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

I tested this contact with Remix and it works fine, values are added and I'm able to see them. But I need to do this from Node.js and so far it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `call` in the code below is incorrect.

```
myContract.methods.add(0, web3.utils.asciiToHex("some string")).call()
  .then(receipt => {
      console.log(" added? " + receipt); // returns [object Object]
});
```

This is a common mistake. `call` is used to run functions on a local VM and is not broadcast out to the blockchain for mining. Any change to state needs to use `send`: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I guess I need to sign the `send` transaction? If you have a full example I'd appreciate it.

Comment: OK I'm seeing the examples in the link you sent. I'll try that and if successful I'll accept the answer. Thanks.